# May I ask this question or will it be closed?

Tags: support, on-topic-ness, specific-question

I'd like to know if I can get more specific than a checklist to understand whether or not my research paper (at the graduate level for getting my M.Sc.) is good enough to publish anywhere. It's been reviewed and approved by professors, and personally, I think it stands on its own and is unique for being a survey of the latest and most efficient algorithms in a particular part of geometric problems, and making the results intelligible for a non-expert audience. However I find no objective measure to apply myself, and I would prefer to let somebody else read it before I try to submit it for publication or even put it online.

Answer (score 5):

The content of research including evaluation of your specific paper is off topic here.

If you link to your work it might appear like spam; while it may not be your personal intent, other people try to use this site in a self-promotion way. We do not permit that.

The people to ask would be the professors who have reviewed your work, your masters advisor in particular.

Comment: I see that questions are accepted asking "What are the criteria for XYZ to be accepted". I'm worried that it's true what they said about research that reviews and responses are worse than random decisions.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz There's certainly randomness to the publication process, which is pretty expected if you give it some thought; if you have 2-3 reviewers for a paper, and not everyone agrees about whether it should be published, then the decision depends on which group those 2-3 individuals are drawn from. The broader concept of what is *publishable* is not as random, though it takes a lot of expert work to evaluate a given project and decide. So, the person you should ask is someone personally invested in your success, like your MSc advisor.

Comment: If it's a survey paper, it's not *research* in the academic sense of original work advancing knowledge, so it's a matter of whether there's sufficient need in the area you wrote it in that it would be useful enough to others to be published.